# Comparison based on Dates

Tags: cql, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have one table in Cassandra :-

```
CREATE TABLE printerload (
    gp_date timestamp,
    printed_cost float,
    printed_pages int,
    saved_cost float,
    saved_pages int,
    PRIMARY KEY (gp_date)
)
```

I have inserted data in the table :-

```
cqlsh> select * from ga.printerload;

gp_date                  | printed_cost | printed_pages | saved_cost | saved_pages
--------------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------
2012-01-02 10:30:00-0800 |          0.2 |             2 |          0 |           0
2013-07-10 11:30:00-0700 |        22633 |        322304 |      54.72 |         142
2012-12-15 10:30:00-0800 |       952.17 |         13524 |       0.18 |           3
2013-01-25 10:30:00-0800 |       1982.2 |         26006 |       0.66 |           0
2013-02-26 10:30:00-0800 |        23189 |        335584 |      61.44 |          84
2012-07-16 11:30:00-0700 |        25312 |        338318 |      13.16 |          25
2012-09-26 11:30:00-0700 |        19584 |        287148 |      98.64 |         319
2012-02-09 10:30:00-0800 |         5.01 |            33 |       0.12 |           0
2012-08-19 11:30:00-0700 |        21833 |        323918 |      28.42 |         395
2013-05-09 11:30:00-0700 |        16493 |        235701 |      30.27 |         232
2013-06-14 11:30:00-0700 |       681.41 |          9087 |          0 |           0
2012-08-04 11:30:00-0700 |       610.91 |          8533 |          0 |           0
2012-06-04 11:30:00-0700 |        22793 |        317440 |       4.09 |           4
2013-07-30 11:30:00-0700 |        22037 |        322377 |      34.83 |          79
2012-08-20 11:30:00-0700 |        22760 |        334601 |       8.48 |          17
```

I want to search on the basis of date (I am inserting data using Java client, where gp_date is only date, e.g. 2013-07-30). I did a query :-

```
cqlsh> select * from ga.printerload WHERE gp_date = '2013-07-30';

(0 rows)
```

I need to include time part as well to search.

```
cqlsh> select * from ga.printerload WHERE gp_date = '2013-07-30 11:30:00-0700';

gp_date                  | printed_cost | printed_pages | saved_cost | saved_pages
--------------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+-------------
2013-07-30 11:30:00-0700 |        22037 |        322377 |      34.83 |          79
```

But the comparison should be only on the basis of date (I want to get records for a specific day, irrespective of time). How can I do that? Is there any method which can compare only date part? I am using Apache Cassandra 2.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your id data type form timestamp to date, after that you have to change your primary key because on a given date there should be many printerload so make it a normal columns and use secondary indexes to query on that column.

I think it should work for you.

Comment: But there is no Date data type in Cassandra. Isn't it?